# Jenkins Login Plugin Advice

Tags: java, authentication, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to create a Jenkins Authentication plugin that does this:

- User arrives at the jenkins login page and enters username and password
- plugin receives username and password (SecurityRealm.createSecurityComponents() etc.) and submits the credentials to a third party system that returns an MFA prompt.
- Plugin takes the user to a 'page' or in some other way notifies the user of the MFA prompt and allows them to enter their MFA response
- Plugin completes login and returns SecurityComponents etc.

I think what I'm asking is, what is the best way to intercept the Jenkins login process such that I can provide an MFA challenge page?
Do I need to get involved in Spring Filters or is there some more Jenkins Native way to do this?